# virtualenv: how to switching global site packages inheritance on and off?

Tags: python, virtualenv, dependency-management, package-management

In virtualenv, the option to inherit site packages from parent seems to be determined when it was created, and cannot be modified later.

This has created great inconvenience for dependency management, e.g. when the venv is referenced and dereferenced in Pycharm:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-38221?project=PY&clearDraft=true&description=PC-192.6817.19,%20JRE%2011.0.4%2010-b304.69x64%20JetBrains%20s.r.o,%20OS%20Linux(amd64)%20v5.0.0-29-generic,%20screens%201920x1080

The inheritance will be permanently disabled and never found again.

Is my impression correct? If not, what is the easiest way to achieve this feature?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember just recreate the virtualenv with the same target directory and with or without the --system-site-packages and it should toggle.

It least with older versions of virtualenv this worked if I recall correctly

Answer (score 0):

[virtualenvwrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtualenvwrapper) has a command [`toggleglobalsitepackages`](https://bitbucket.org/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper/src/0e9ff6d9409573ca23e4e4db77ee0640bf98ec44/virtualenvwrapper.sh#lines-954).

Comment: Sounds promising, unfortunately it only applies to environments created by this utility

Comment: All it does — creates or removes file `no-global-site-packages.txt`. `virtualenv` [does that](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/blob/35218c9ff4d90dd436f7c9a4d8eb10fc23d792e9/virtualenv.py#L1464) but only on creation. So I think you can just create/remove it manually.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Let me try if I can remove it

Comment: yes. adding / removing no-global-site-packages.txt should be sufficient.